# Kindle 5th Generation MOBI files not showing up in the Books app

Tags: kindle, epub, mobi, kindle-fire

I'm converting my EPUB files to MOBI files (in Calibre, "both" file format, stripped the [PDOC] tag, put in the [EBOK] tag). After transferring them via USB and dropping them in the Books folder and they are finally showing on my home screen in the Books section. But, when I click on the "See all of your books" link, those books don't show up in the Books app.

I've click on "All" or "Downloaded" and it doesn't make a difference.

Why aren't these showing up properly?

Comment: are you able to add a small test `PDF` file and read from the Kindle?